# Protest closed question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434517/pgraphicimage-not-rendering-image) and got an answer. This however led to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506762/display-uploaded-image-in-jsf). The second question was closed and marked as an "exact duplicate" of the first question.

At first the questions may seem alike, because the code posted looks alike.
When someone actually reads the questions there is a notable difference. In the first setup the data is stored in a database, in the second the data is only in-memory.

Now I cannot discuss if the question was closed justly and I'm stuck with a closed question, and thus I have to come here for an explanation.

In short, is the second question closed justly? If so why? If not, what can I do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options in my opinion: (assuming of course you have strong and clear case to reopen)

1. In case it was closed by a moderator, ask him via a comment to reopen explaining your reason. (e.g. @George please reopen [yada yada]..)
2. Flag your own question for moderator attention, choose Other and explain.
3. If both of the above failed (e.g. you tried them but whole day passed and still closed) then you can come here and users might come for the rescue.

Answer (score 8):

You would have been (and may still be) well advised to explicitly link to your earlier question and to explain (again, explicitly) the differences.

And you can still post comments on closed questions.